# javascript enable/disable textfield/file field onfocus event problem on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onfocus

```
 Use default: 
 <input type="radio" name="restype" value="resdef" onfocus="document.getElementById('resupload').disabled = true; document.getElementById('resadres').disabled = true;" checked="checked" /><br />

 Adres: 
 <input type="radio" name="restype" value="resadres" onfocus="document.getElementById('resupload').disabled = true; document.getElementById('resadres').disabled = false;" /> 
 <input type="text" name="resadres" id="resadres" disabled="disabled" /><br /><br />

 Upload: 
 <input type="radio" name="restype" value="resupload" onfocus="document.getElementById('resadres').disabled = true;  document.getElementById('resupload').disabled = false;" /> 
 <input type="file" name="resupload" id="resupload" disabled="disabled" />
```

This code works in firefox and IE but not in Chrome. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onfocus` works when you use tab key to navigate. You should use `onchange` event for form elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/5NaH5/